# Should Bit Errors Cause Loss Proportional To PDU Size?

Tags: fiber, icmp, packet-loss, ber

Should I expect random (or even regularly-occurring) bit errors to cause corrupted/dropped PDUs (packets) proportionate to the PDU size ?

Troubleshooting high (0.01% to 0.1%) packet loss over a short (<1ms) 2-hop path, 1Gbps+.

I ran these two pings concurrently.
Pretty sure their combined traffic volume shouldn't be enough to cause (too much) contention between the two.
Would probably do well to gather a larger sample size / longer run, but here we are for now.

```
ping -c 1200001 -s    4 -W 2 -qni 0.001 10.0.0.1
    --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
    1200001 packets transmitted, 1199002 received, 0.0832499% packet loss, time 1222942ms

ping -c 1200002 -s 1192 -W 2 -qni 0.001 10.0.0.1
    --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
    1200002 packets transmitted, 1199224 received, 0.0648332% packet loss, time 1235676ms
```

Wouldn't we expect (over a long enough sampling period) for the 1220 byte packets to be dropped proportionately more often than the 32 byte packets ?

Yet above, the 32 byte packets see higher loss ...
Can we reasonably infer, then, that the cause of the loss is likely *not* bit-error-related ?

Bonus : Someone advised me that ...

> 32 byte packets are far more lossy then 1220, because of all the excessive headers, and CRCs and so forth.

Is this true ?
What is the mechanism behind smaller packets being inherently more lossy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I expect random (or even regularly-occurring) bit errors to cause corrupted/dropped PDUs (packets) proportionate to the PDU size ?

Yes - for truly random errors. However, most often transmission errors are not entirely random but more likely with specific patterns (especially on copper) which are not trivial.

`ping`ing doesn't provide really useful probing as ICMP packets can be dropped for a variety of reasons, not just checksum errors (esp. ICMP rate limiting, processing contention, QoS).

If you really want to troubleshoot packet loss on a multi-hop path, check the error counters on all intermediate devices' interfaces while you fire some high-bandwidth streams across the links in each direction and both simultaneously. Anything flaky should show up.